# How to change activeEditor in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

How can I change activeEditor programetically in tinyMCE.
Ex:
Like if I have two editors in same page, How can I switch between them programetically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get any instance of TinyMCE by `tinyMCE.get('field-name')` or by `tinyMCE['field-name']` here field name will be the field **TinyMCE** is associated with.

Answer (score 2):

The activeEditor will switch when you focus a different editor so the method is to call focus on the editor you want to be active. You can choose to not actually focus the editor by passing `false`.
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#focus

Extract from that page:

> ### focus
>
> `focus(skipFocus:Boolean)`
>
> Focuses/activates the editor. This will set this editor as the
> activeEditor in the tinymce collection it will also place DOM focus
> inside the editor.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - `skipFocus` (Boolean) - Skip DOM focus. Just set is as the active editor.